# React - List?Dictionary?State? Or am i missing something

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's start off with the problem I'm having and telling you guys what I would like to achieve.

First of all, I'm getting this error

```
Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. 
Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

My goal is to save data first to the state. Or I should use List, or dictionary? This is where I'm stuck. I will post my code here also for you to check what I'm doing wrong or what should I do differently.

```
    import React from 'react'
    import './TableData.css'


    class TableData extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
          super(props)
          this.state = {
            rows:[{service: '',
            quantity: '',
            price: '',
            sum: ''}]
          }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
      this.handleAddRow = this.handleAddRow.bind(this)
      this.handleRemoveRow = this.handleRemoveRow.bind(this)
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)

    }

      handleChange = idx => event => {
        var rows = [...this.state.rows]
        rows[idx] = {
         [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
        this.setState({
          rows
        })
        var data = this.state.rows
        console.log("Log me", data)
      }

      handleAddRow = () => {
        var item = {
          service: '',
          quantity: '',
          price: '',
          sum: ''
        }
        this.setState({
          rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
        })
      }

      handleRemoveRow = () => {
        this.setState({
          rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
        })
      }

      handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
        var tableData = this.state.rows
        console.log("Final data is:", tableData)
    }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="tablePos container" >
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <div className="row">
                  <table id="tab_logic">
                    <thead className="tableBackground">
                      <tr>
                        <th className="col-md-auto"> Service </th>
                        <th className="col col-lg-2"> Quantity </th>
                        <th className="col col-lg-2"> Price </th>
                        <th className="col col-lg-2"> Sum </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                        <tr key={idx}>
                          <td>
                            <input className="form-control" type="text" name="service" placeholder="Ex: Cloud Service" value={this.state.rows[idx].service} onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}/>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input className="form-control" type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Ex: 2 Month" value={this.state.rows[idx].quantity} onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}/>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input className="form-control" type="text" name="price" placeholder="Ex: 75.00" value={this.state.rows[idx].price} onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}/>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <input className="form-control" type="text" name="sum" placeholder="Ex: 150.00" value={this.state.rows[idx].sum} onChange={this.handleChange(idx)} />
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </div>
                  <button>Send Data!</button>
                  </form>
                  <button onClick={this.handleAddRow} className="btn btn-success">Add Row</button>
                  <button onClick={this.handleRemoveRow} className="btn btn-danger">Delete Last Row</button>
              </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default TableData
```

So basically it creates 4 input boxes and then you can write in and if you are done you click Send Data it saves it to state or add new row and then it will add new row for you to input data. What I do get is the following from that code.

[Console log picture of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV5jK.png)

It only saves the last input field data when I click send data not all of them.

Sorry about my messy explanation but I hope you did understand my problem and thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while assigning the values inside `onChange`. You are spreading the array as needed. But you have to spread the object too.. Otherwise, it will just assign the last-changed-input-field-value to the object.

```
rows[idx] = {
      ...this.state.rows[idx],
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    };
```

You can find my code below.
https://codesandbox.io/s/small-dew-wjqqi

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: well.. great.. i could help u. @RasmusRugam now if this solved your case.. it would be great if you could just upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: any possible way to get contact with you?

Comment: @RasmusRugam you can join me.. here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210276/itzbkp